# Custom Attribute - get value of underlying enum

Tags: c#, attributes, enums

I'm not sure of all of the correct terminology for what I am trying to do, so I will just dive in with some code.

Current Setup:

```
public enum NavigationLinks
{
    [FriendlyName("System Dashboard")]
    SystemDashboard,
    [FriendlyName("Trading Dashboard")]
    TradingDashboard,
}

public class UINameAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string Value { get; private set; }

    public UINameAttribute(string Value)
    {
        this.Value = Value;
    }
}
```

What I would like:

```
public enum NavigationLinks
{
    [FriendlyName]
    SystemDashboard,
    [FriendlyName]
    TradingDashboard,
}

public class UINameAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string Value { get; private set; }

    public UINameAttribute(string Value)
    {
        this.Value = Value;
    }

    public UINameAttribute()
    {
        string AttributedValue = this.AttributedObject.ToString();
        // Take the value of the attribute and add a space in between the camel case.
    }
}
```

Can I access the underlying 'thing' that the attribute is on from within the constructor of the attribute?

Comment: Does `this.AttributedObject.ToString()` return `SystemDashboard` or `TradingDashboard` ?

Comment: You are still going to have to access your attribute's value against the reflected member at some point anyway. So you would put your additional logic in there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't access attributed member from within the attribute's constructor.

But why do that anyway, if you already have a logic how to resolve friendly name from enum value.

```
public enum NavigationLinks
{
    SystemDashboard,
    TradingDashboard,
}

public static class Program
{
    private static string ToFriendlyName(string defaultName)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder(defaultName);

        for (int i = 1; i < sb.Length; ++i)
            if (char.IsUpper(sb[i]))
            {
                sb.Insert(i, ' ');
                ++i;
            }

        return sb.ToString();
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var value = NavigationLinks.SystemDashboard;

        var friendlyName = ToFriendlyName(value.ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Stipo's approach you can also write an extension method to get the name, something like this:

```
public static class NavigationLinksExtension
{
    public static string GetFriendlyName(this NavigationLinks navLink)
    {
        string tmpName = navLink.ToString();
        tmpName = Regex.Replace(tmpName, "(?<=[a-z])([A-Z])", " $1"); // insert space
        return tmpName;
    }
}
```

Then you can simply access the value:

```
NavigationLinks nl = NavigationLinks.TradingDashboard;
string nlFriendlyName = nl.GetFriendlyName();
```

Answer (score 2):

An attribute can't (directly) get access to the thing it is describing.  If you want ToString() to be the default and only override it occasionally, you would be better off with a helper function (e.g. GetFriendlyName) that defaults to ToString(), but replaces it with the value in a FriendlyName attribute should one exist.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following:

```
var inputString = NavigationLinks.SystemDashboard;
Regex.Replace(inputString, "([A-Z][a-z0-9]+)+", "$1$2");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [DescriptionAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.componentmodel.descriptionattribute.aspx) (or create a custom attribute), then, using Reflection to get the value:

Create the class EnumDescriptions (using System.ComponentModel and System.Reflection):

```
public class EnumDescriptions
{
    public static string StringValueOf(Enum value)
    {
        FieldInfo fieldInfo = value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString());

        DescriptionAttribute[] attributes = (DescriptionAttribute[])fieldInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);

        return attributes[0].Description;
    }
```

And put Description in the Enum:

```
    public enum Animals
    {
        [Description("System Dashboard")]
        SystemDashboard,
        [Description("Trading Dashboard")]
        TradingDashboard,
    }
```

To get the values:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(EnumDescriptions.StringValueOf(Animals.SystemDashboard));
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine(EnumDescriptions.StringValueOf(Animals.TradingDashboard));
        Console.Read();
    }
```